# Iterate through the dictionary in alphabetical order

Tags: python

I have a dict in my python code. I need to iterate through all its elements in the order of the sorted keys. in C++, I do it like this:

```
map<string, int> my_map;
my_map["ccc"] = 3;
my_map["aaa"] = 1;
my_map["bbb"] = 2;
for (auto item : my_map)
{
    cout << item.second << endl;
}
```

The output is:

```
1
2
3
```

But if I try to do similar actions in python, the output order changes:

```
my_dict = dict()
my_dict['ccc'] = 3
my_dict['aaa'] = 1
my_dict['bbb'] = 2
for item in my_dict.items():
    print(item[1])
```

The output is:

```
3
1
2
```

How can I iterate over a dict in python in the same order as unordered_map in c++?

Comment: Try `for item in sorted(my_dict.items()):`

Answer (score 1):

Sort the items first before iterating:

```
for item in sorted(my_dict.items()):
    print(item[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in sorted(dict.items()):
   print(i)
```